# Ajax is not working in the view

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am new to .net mvc, and I am trying to create a simple page which requests and submits the form. When I am using Ajax for httppost request, the page isn't posting/redirecting.

Js file

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("form").submit(function (e) {


            var obj = { 

                Id : @Model.Id,
                Name : '@Model.Name',
                City : '@Model.City',
                Gender : '@Model.Gender',
                Dob : '@Model.Dob'

            };

            $.ajax({

                url: '@Url.Action("Edit","Employee")',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify(obj),
                success: function (result) {

                    alert("Success");
                },

                failed: function (result) {

                    alert("Failed");
                }

            });

            return false;

        });

    });

</script>
```

cshtml view here

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Employee</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Gender, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("Gender", new List<SelectListItem>
           {
               new SelectListItem { Text = "Male" , Value = "Male"},
               new SelectListItem { Text = "Female" , Value = "Female"}
           }, "Select Gender" , new { @class = "form-control"}) 
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gender, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.City, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Dob, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Dob, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Dob, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Controller code here

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Employee emp)
        {            
            EmployeeBusinessLayer employeeBusinessLayer = new EmployeeBusinessLayer();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                employeeBusinessLayer.Modify("Edit", emp);

                return View();
            }

            else return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
```

When I click on 'Save', nothing happens ! What am I missing here ?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? What is the point of posting back the original model values that you just sent to the browser. And what errors are you getting in the browser console?

Comment: have you check your console? for any errors?

Comment: Can you share the controller code too? What you expect to happen in the Post call at controller side?

Comment: And what do you mean _not redirecting_ - its an ajax call and ajax calls never redirect - the whole point of them is to stay on the same page.

Comment: Added controller code.

I 'm trying to fetch the form details and send it to controller, controller will call a method to add these data into a database.

 I'm assuming "Employee emp" parameter will be the data fetched from ajax post method. Is that the way it works ?

Comment: Edit your question - not in comments! (but that has nothing to do with your issue). And read the previous comments - what do you thing your trying to do here? - your attempting to send back the original model, not the edited values, and ajax calls do not redirect. Just make a normal submit and delete your script.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use  **e.preventDefault();** in your submit method like below:

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("form").submit(function (e) {

            e.preventDefault(); //prevent default form submit
            var obj = { 

                Id : @Model.Id,
                Name : '@Model.Name',
                City : '@Model.City',
                Gender : '@Model.Gender',
                Dob : '@Model.Dob'

            };

            $.ajax({

                url: '@Url.Action("Edit","Employee")',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify(obj),
                success: function (result) {

                    alert("Success");
                },

                failed: function (result) {

                    alert("Failed");
                }

            });

            return false;

        });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Seriously - 5 upvotes for a wrong answer. OP already has `return false;` in the script so `e.preventDefault();` is completely unnecessary. And this has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: I have checked it, He missed the e.preventDefault(); which made the page to post.

   
   I think you are happy to point out, not to solve.
Read the comment below ! 

That helped, Thanks ! As @Stephen had pointed out, I was trying to post the same data. Anyway, I am still struggling to pass an "Employee" object back to controller ! – Harsha Rao 23 hours ago

Comment: Read my comment again. Using `return false;` prevents the form from submitting. Adding `e.preventDefault();` is just doing the same thing! And it would not matter if both were lines were deleted - the ajax call will still be made in addition to the normal submit. Again. this has nothing to do with OP's issue. And its clear from their comments that they have no idea what they are doing and have not shown the relevant code.The question cannot be answered because nothing OP is doing makes any sense.

Answer (score 1):

Before defining the obj variable, add this line:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Select the inputs like this:

```
var obj: {
   Id: $('Id').val(),
   Name: $('#Name').val(),
   City: $('#City').val(),
   Dob: $('#Dob').val(),
   Gender: $("#Gender option:selected").val()
}
```

Comment: That helped, Thanks !  As @Stephen had pointed out, I was trying to post the same data.
 Anyway, I am still struggling to pass an "Employee" object back to controller !

Comment: OP already has `return false` so `e.preventDefault();` is unnecessary. And this has nothing to do with the fact the script is not executing.

Comment: It alerted me success, when I did run now. But I'm handling the data wrongly in a controller. I am unsure, how to handle this data in a httpost method. I did use a parameter, which is wrong I believe.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint to Edit method in the Controller? Is Employee object null?

Comment: Yes, I see a null Employee object !

Comment: I did a typo `Id: $('Id').val()` must be `Id: $('#Id').val(),`
After defining obj variable, `console.log(obj);` then `Ctrl + Shift + I` on the Chrome, look the Console tab to see the obj's value.

Comment: The obj returns a value in the console, and for Id, I'm using @Model.id as it should be static. Something in Ajax which isn't posting the data to the controller.

Comment: Change the edit method like this:
`public ActionResult Edit([FromBody]Employee emp)`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the controller code you've posted, change this part of your View:

```
    $("form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({

            url: '@Url.Action("Edit","Employee")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $("form").serialize(),
            success: function (result) {

                alert("Success");
            },

            failed: function (result) {

                alert("Failed");
            }

        });

        return false;

    });
```

You should also change your controller as you shouldn't be returning a `View();` but that's another thing altogether...

Comment: $("form").serialize() . this didn't work either. Can you please brief me how a controller handles ajax data ? How can I send an "Employee" object to the method when its method is of type "Employee" ?